# NSLayoutConstraint does not work properly in ios 10.0 or below but works in 11.0

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

This is programmatically coded for alert controller:

[image: *This*]  It's working well in `iOS` `11.0` and above but i get conflict in `iOS` `10.0` and below

```
let vc = UIViewController()
var height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.6, constant: vc.view.frame.height * 0.53)
alert.view.addConstraint(height);
if(isIPadTrait){
    height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.6, constant: vc.view.frame.height * 0.4)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes that there is a `height` constraint defined in the alert view, which may or may not be the case.  The view certainly has a defined height but it may be computed dynamically in older releases or not using layout constraints.